# How do I sum the results of a select that returns multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql

I have a SQL variable `@SumScore dec(9,4)`

I am trying to assign the variable as follows:

```
SET @SumScore =   
        (  
            SELECT Sum(  
                (  
                    SELECT SUM(etjs.CalculatedScore * sc.PercentOfTotal) as CategoryScore   
                    FROM tblEventTurnJudgeScores etjs 
                        INNER JOIN tblJudgingCriteria jc ON  jc.JudgingCriteriaID = etjs.JudgingCriteriaID  
                        INNER JOIN tblScoringCategories sc ON jc.ScoringCategoryID = sc.ScoringCategoryID  
                    GROUP BY jc.JudgingCriteriaID  
                ) 
            As ComputedScore) AS SumTotalScore  
        )
```

In other words the inner select is returning one column. I want the var to be assigned the SUM of all of the rows that are being return there.

I realize that this could be done with a temp table pretty easily. But is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SET @SumScore = SELECT SUM(etjs.CalculatedScore * sc.PercentOfTotal) as CategoryScore   
                  FROM tblEventTurnJudgeScores etjs 
                  JOIN tblJudgingCriteria jc ON  jc.JudgingCriteriaID = etjs.JudgingCriteriaID  
                  JOIN tblScoringCategories sc ON jc.ScoringCategoryID = sc.ScoringCategoryID
```

There's no point to using `GROUP BY jc.JudgingCriteriaID` if the outer query is going to sum up everything anyway.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT Sum(CategoryScore)
FROM ( subquery )
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me like this:

```
select sum(myColumn) from MyTable where MyTableID = 'some value'
```

you could also do this (to make it more robust):

```
select sum(isnull(myColumn,0)) from MyTable where MyTableID = 'some value'
```